# Implementar Filterable a un BaseAdapter Personalizado - Android

Tags: java, android, gridview

Tengo el siguiente adaptador personalizado para un `GridView` :

```
public class AdapterGrid extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private List<String> items;


    public AdapterGrid(Context contexto, int layout, List<String> items) {

        this.context = contexto;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.items = items;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.items.size() ;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        /////PATRO VIEW HOLDER


        View  inflateView = convertView;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        inflateView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_stamp, null);

        //// esto reemplaza el getItem
        String currentName = items.get(pos);
        TextView numberStamp = inflateView.findViewById(R.id.numberstamp);
        numberStamp.setText(""+pos);

        return inflateView;

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

y aquí lo  Creo:

```
   final AdapterGrid itemsAdapter = new AdapterGrid(this, R.layout.grid_stamp, nitems);
        gridView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
```

Necesito implementar un `Filter` para ese `gridview`, es decir que al ir escribiendo en un `edittext` pueda ir filtrando, he implementado el `Filterable`, pero no se como hacer para que vaya filtrando, gracias.

> - ACTUALIZADO -

No sabia que se podia hacer con el método de @YorchSircam , y sin implementar filterable pude solucionarlo, hago una copia de Items, y creo un método en el que busca el texto que envía el usuario agregando en él los que vaya encontrando y mostrando la lista copiada:

```
 public void filtrar(String texto){
        //aca implementas tu filtro a como gustes, ejemplo



        for (String object: this.items) {
            Log.v(" ♠ FILTRAR true |","TEXTO  ***"+texto+ " CONTENTARRAY "+object);

        }

        itemsMostrados.clear();
        int possearch;
        for (String object: this.items) {
            possearch=object.indexOf(texto);
            if(possearch > -1){
                itemsMostrados.add(object);
            }

        }



        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

 public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        /////PATRO VIEW HOLDER
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_stamp, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.numeroestampilla = convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberstamp);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else{

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //// esto reemplaza el getItem
        String currentName = itemsMostrados.get(pos);
        holder.numeroestampilla.setText(""+pos+" "+currentName);

        return convertView;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No he usado filterable, pero te propongo algo que tal vez te sea util.
Puedes implementar un método publico en tu adapter, y conforme escribas, le mandas el string a ese método para ir filtrando e ir actualizando la lista. Puedes tener 2 listas en este caso, una lista con todos los items originales, y otra lista de los items que vas a desplegar.

```
public class AdapterGrid extends BaseAdapter{
        private List<String> items, itemsMostrados;

        public AdapterGrid(..., List<String> items){
            this.items = items;
            itemsMostrados.addAll(items);
        }

        public void filtrar(String texto){
          //aca implementas tu filtro a como gustes, ejemplo
          itemsMostrados.clear();
          for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
              if(items.get(i).indexOf(texto)) 
                  itemsMostrados.add(items.get(i));
          }
          notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.itemsMostrados.size() ;
        }
```

Y en donde este el input para tu filtro puedes hacer uso de el asi

```
mFiltro.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            mAdapter.filter(charSequence.toString());
        }
```

Comment: :s casi, ahora cuando  escribo algo en el input se borra todo :S, en el getView debo caambiar algo?

Comment: @AndressBlend, si en tu getview haces referencia a "items" pero deberias hacer referencia a "itemsMostrados", asi que en lugar de String currentName = items.get(pos);, haces String currentName = itemsMostrados.get(pos);

Comment: ya masomenso voy enteniendo, pero mira que en el primer filtro sirve, porque me dice que items.size = 5 , pero después siempre es 0, hice pruebas y items  agarra el valor de items mostrados, en ingun lugar estoy haciendo items = items mostrados, pero pareciera que el mismo adapter le pasara los valores de items mostrados a  items :(

Comment: cambiaste @Override public int getCount() a como lo puse?, ahi intenta imprimir cuanto mide items e itemsMostrados

Comment: Sip, lo hice pero daba error porque itemsMostrados de inicio es 0, entonces lo que o hacia era igualarlo a los items del constructor pero por alguna extraña razon que desconozco era si como si se enlazaran items e itemsmostrados y si modificaba uno el otro también lo hacia, entonces lo que hice fue un foreach a lo que recibe en el constructor y uno a uno agregarlo a items Mostrados y por fin funcionó!!!!! hay cosas que no se porque funcionaron pero me alegra, gracias por tu ayuda !

Comment: @AndressBlend ah si, ya entendi, creo que de hecho si es un error mio en el codigo, en el constructor deberias haber copiado los items a itemsMostrados. Para que quede mejor, puedes usar un addAll(), lo voy a agregar a la respuesta para que quede completa