# Filtro a listview con adaptador personalizado con datos sqlite

Tags: android, base-de-datos

yo estoy realizando un proyecto de productos en base de datos local muy similar al proyecto que consultó el usuario Bruno Sosa Fast Tag [Filtro Android Studio , ListView Con adapter Perzonalizado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111995/filtro-android-studio-listview-con-adapter-perzonalizado)
 y el usuario David Minaya le ayudo, he aplicado la solucion que aplico David Minaya y no me filtra ningun dato solo se borra la lista y no aparece mas no se que estoy haciendo mal, si me podrian ayudar se los agradeceria un monton gracias.

esta es mi clase lista3 que seria el equivalente a la clase contactos del ejemplo.

```html
public class Lista3 {
    private String Id, Usuario;
    private byte[]Imagen;

    public Lista3(String id,String usuario, byte[] imagen) {
        super();
        Id=id;
        Usuario = usuario;
        Imagen = imagen;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Usuario = id;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return Usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        Usuario = usuario;
    }

    public byte[] getImagen() {
        return Imagen;
    }

    public void setImagen(byte[] imagen) {
        Imagen = imagen;
    }

}
```

este es mi clase adaptador.

```html
public class AdaptadorLista3 extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Lista3> list;
        ArrayList<Lista3> copylist=new ArrayList<>();


        public AdaptadorLista3(Context context,ArrayList<Lista3> list) {
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;
            this.copylist.addAll(list);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Lista3 item=(Lista3)getItem(position);
            convertView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_lista_usuarios,null);
            ImageView imgfoto= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imvicono);
            TextView Usuario= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblUsuario);
            TextView Id= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblIdUsuario);

            byte[] icono=item.getImagen();
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(icono, 0, icono.length);
            imgfoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Usuario.setText(item.getUsuario());
            Id.setText(item.getId());
            return convertView;

        }

        /* Filtra los datos del adaptador */
        public void filtrar(String texto) {
            // Elimina todos los datos del ArrayList que se cargan en los
            // elementos del adaptador
            list.clear();

            // Si no hay texto: agrega de nuevo los datos del ArrayList copiado
            // al ArrayList que se carga en los elementos del adaptador
            if (texto.length() == 0) {
                list.addAll(copylist);
            } else {

                // Recorre todos los elementos que contiene el ArrayList copiado
                // y dependiendo de si estos contienen el texto ingresado por el
                // usuario los agrega de nuevo al ArrayList que se carga en los
                // elementos del adaptador.
                for (Lista3 lista3 : copylist) {

                    if (lista3.getUsuario().contains(texto)) {
                        list.add(lista3);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Actualiza el adaptador para aplicar los cambios
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }
```

y lo ejecuto de esta manera.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                adaptadorLista3.filtrar(Buscar.getText().toString());

                }
```

no se en que me estaría equivocando, los datos lo estoy llenando desde sqlite solicito su ayuda por favor.

Comment: checa esta pregunta [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150947/implementar-filterable-a-un-baseadapter-personalizado-android/150970#150970) puede que te sea util

Comment: Los nombres de los usuarios que buscas, comienzan con Mayúscula? Y si es así, cuando buscas los nombres los estas escribiendo en minúscula?

Comment: no es por las mayusculas, el problema es que la inicio donde hace la copia de la lista el copylist no obtiene ningun valor porque inicia en 0, pero ya lo solucione gracias.